# Some style attributes are missing after migrating from support library to AndroidX

Tags: android, androidx

By refering to https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/res/layout/simple_spinner_item.xml and https://pep-security.lu/gitlab/android/pep/blame/2f5b1397ba73f78f49f2094b9fb370d2fee62635/k9mail/src/main/res/layout/simple_spinner_item.xml

Currently, we have the following dropdown view item. It is using style `?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle`

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp">

    <CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/checked_text_view_0"
        style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:minHeight="48dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

We use the above XML in a custom `ArrayAdapter`. The custom `ArrayAdapter` will then attached to `Spinner`

```
repeatInfoSpinner.setAdapter(repeatInfoArrayAdapter);
```

When we are using support library (Before migrating to AndroidX), it looks like this. It comes with nice touch ripple effect.

[image]

---

After migrating to AndroidX, it looks like legacy holo design.

[image]

---

It seems that, the style attribute which is previously found in support library (https://chromium.googlesource.com/android_tools/+/bf45c76e0eb23b7b7a9d5f26b28c16983daa173b/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/res/values/themes.xml#33) , no longer found in AndroidX.

---

May I know, how can we resolve such, to make our app looks like material design app?

Note, I had tried `?attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle`. It makes no difference.

Comment: There's a separate Material Design package by Google's [material.io](https://material.io/) that you can also use, here's the [repo](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android). Also, there is no `spinnerDropDownItemStyle` instead there is [Widget.MaterialComponents.PopupMenu](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/menu/res/values-v23/styles.xml)

Comment: Hem... Is that some official lib from Google?

Comment: It is from Google. But, it's not bundled with standard Android packages. The contributors are Google employees and it's linked by the Material.io (which is the primer for Material Design) web page as well as Google's developer blog posts.

Comment: Are you using Spinner or CheckedTextView?

Comment: We use Spinner.

Comment: please check dialog and activity theme ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i try simple demo in androidx

```
 <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"/>
```

and code side simple arrayAdapter give me correct result

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

val list = listOf<String>("das","fsdfs","fsdfsd","fsdfsd")

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    spinner.adapter = ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list)
}
}
```

Still problem if you have problem , please check Dialog and Activity style theme.

please look below result of mine

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Changing my spinner style from `<style name="ReminderSpinnerStyle.Brown" parent="android:style/Widget.ListView.DropDown">` to `<style name="ReminderSpinnerStyle.Brown" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ListView.DropDown">` solve the problem.

Comment: Welcome , mainly theme issue is there ? @CheokYanCheng

Comment: @CheokYanCheng ain't i winner of the bounty ?

Comment: Yes. You will :) But, Stack overflow system will only allow me to award it in next 24 hours, after the answer is accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I was having some similar problems before, turns out you have to change the ways you refer to these styles, they are more "Object-oriented" now in AndroidX. In your case, I think you would use something like:

```
style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.DropDownItem.Spinner"
```

instead of the original:

```
?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle
```

If it doesn't resolve, remember to check your gradle file and see if androidx's appcompat dependency is there, it should be something like this:

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha04'
```

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Is the attribute not being resolved or is it not the one you wanted?